# Recommendation for creating a graphical timeline representation

Tags: publications, phd, graduate-school, writing, undergraduate

Can anyone recommend a site / program / software for sketching and creating a graphical timeline representation. In need of it for a paper.

Comment: Well, you can do many things in Excel, even use conditional formatting to color rows or columns of cells according to calculations, which could form the basis of a timeline. Then other cells could pick up appropriate labels/text using index() with match() for example.

Comment: @Biolsaac sounds like something any generic drawing app and most word processors and presentation apps can do. Even MS Paint works. But I suppose this is off topic anyway. Try software recommendation stack exchange.

Comment: @henning--reinstateMonica I followed your suggestion and was able to make one. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A simple way is to use the [SmartArt](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-timeline-9c4448a9-99c7-4b0e-8eff-0dcf535f223c) feature in various Microsoft Office programs (e.g. PowerPoint) to create a timeline. Google Slides can also be used (Insert -> Diagrams -> Timeline). See e.g. [this guide](https://slidemodel.com/essential-guide-making-timelines/) for more details and inspiration. Alternatively, as henning states in a comment, you can just use a generic drawing app.

TeX solutions also exist, and have been described on other stacks. See e.g.

- [How to create a timeline with LaTeX?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/217834/7492468)
- [How do I develop a complex time line?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/183046/128923)
- [How can you create a vertical timeline?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/196794/128923)